# A graphic is interactive even if is under another graphic

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

I'm quite new with **PIXI** but I expected it to behave somehow like DOM in a web browser.

I've created two *Graphics* (I tried as well with sprite and works in the same way) the first one is *interactive* with *zIndez=1*

```js
var g1 = new PIXI.Graphics();
// ...
g1.x=10;
g1.y=20;
g1.zIndex=1;
g1.interactive=true;
g1.buttonMode=true;
```

For the second one I made it to overlap the first one just leaving 10px visible:

```js
var g2 = new PIXI.Graphics();
//...
g2.x=20;
g2.y=30;
g2.zIndex=2;
```

Clicking on the second one in the overlapped area still fires the event in the first one.

https://jsfiddle.net/hr04y9jz/

I expected the covered area of *g1* not to be clickable

Is this as expected? And if so, There is any kind of work around for this kind of problems?

Thanks in advance.

**edited:**
Somehow seems the opposite problem to this question : [Do not fire interaction listener if something "covering" interactive element was clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62952258/do-not-fire-interaction-listener-if-something-covering-interactive-element-was)

I just tried to replicate this behabiour (but with Graphics) and I couldn't.

Answer (score 1):

> edited: Somehow seems the opposite problem to this question : [Do not fire interaction listener if something "covering" interactive element was clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62952258/do-not-fire-interaction-listener-if-something-covering-interactive-element-was)

As @gman noticed, the solution is to make the `g2` graphics interactive aswell: https://jsfiddle.net/e9r04gjx/

Comment: To be more explicit - g2 may visually cover g1, but if g2 is not set to be interactive, it it ignored by the interaction manager when it hit-tests the click.  Only interactive objects "count" when dealing with interactions (mouse + touch).